# processing, when i write a class in the top of the code, the soundfile is unavalilable

Tags: processing

[image]
this is a part of my code, the error message is "The constructor "SoundFile(Drum, String)" does not exist".

Comment: Did you `import processing.sound.*;`?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] instead of a screenshot of just part of your code?